# How to parse a double from an array of characters using boost::spirit::qi::parse

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-spirit

I can parse numbers from characters stored in std::string, std::vector or std::array.
But I am not able to do so when the characters are in a buffer held in std::unique_ptr.
I could copy the buffer into a string then to boost spirit but I want to avoid this copy

Here is my attempt:

```
#include<memory>
#include<array>
#include<iostream>
#include "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"


int main()
{
    const int max_size = 40;
    std::array<wchar_t, max_size> numeric1;
    std::wstring src = L"5178120.3663";
    std::wcsncpy(numeric1.data(), src.data(), max_size);

    double num = 0.0;
    boost::spirit::qi::parse(numeric1.begin(), numeric1.end(), num);
    std::cout.precision(15);
    std::cout << num << std::endl; // OK

    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> numeric2(new wchar_t[max_size]);
    std::wcsncpy(numeric2.get(), src.data(), max_size);
    std::wcout << L"ok = " << std::wstring(numeric2.get()) << std::endl; // OK

    boost::spirit::qi::parse(numeric2.data(), max_size, num); // fails to compile 
    std::cout.precision(15);
    std::cout << num << std::endl;

    //  'boost::spirit::qi::parse': no matching overloaded function found

    return 0;
}
```

**The fix:**

```
boost::spirit::qi::parse(numeric2.get(), numeric2.get() + wcslen(numeric2.get()), num);
```

See Zalman's anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::spirit::qi::parse` takes a begin and end iterator. You likely want something like:

```
boost::spirit::qi::parse(numeric2.get(), numeric2.get() + wcsnlen(numeric2.get(), max_size), num);
```

I.e. plain pointers work as iterators and you can form the end pointer by adding to the begin one.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please modify as follows and I will accept; boost::spirit::qi::parse(numeric2.get(), numeric2.get() + wcslen(numeric2.get()), num) because it does not compile as is

Comment: Fixed to use wcsnlen, which should match the wide char type and still guarantee not to run off the end of the buffer. In example code it is perhaps best to just hard code the length of the input string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Too many things are off with this:

- unique_ptr doesn't have a `data()` member function
- `qi::parse` doesn't take a size as the second parameter
- you copy indeterminate values liberally to the array/`unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>`
- worse, you even try to parse it. Spirit does not treat NUL characters as special, so you'd "seem" to parse correctly, only because you're ignoring unparsed trailing garbage
- you're mixing `wcout` and `cout` which is unspecified

Here's a fix of most things:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f35879c92c25580a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    const int max_size = 40;
    std::wstring src = L"5178120.3663";
    const int actual_len = src.length() + 1; // include NUL character

    {
        std::array<wchar_t, max_size> numeric1;
        std::wcsncpy(numeric1.data(), src.data(), actual_len);

        double num = 0.0;
        boost::spirit::qi::parse(numeric1.begin(), numeric1.end(), num);
        std::wcout.precision(15);
        std::wcout << num << std::endl; // OK
    }

    {
        std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> numeric2(new wchar_t[max_size]);
        std::wcsncpy(numeric2.get(), src.data(), actual_len);

        double num = 0.0;
        boost::spirit::qi::parse(numeric2.get(), numeric2.get() + actual_len, num);
        std::wcout.precision(15);
        std::wcout << num << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f35879c92c25580a).

Comment: Just curious why add space for null character when wcsncpy will take care of that.

Comment: To be honest I never looked at the docs for `wcsncpy` (my question would be "why use `wcsncpy` or `wcslen` if you already know the length").